# Mail not sending! Firebug shows jQuery error - JS Validation & AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I am unable to send mail.

The link to form is http://thewaitts.com/DemoSite/job.html
Firebug shows some jQuery error that i am not getting.
It was working a few moments ago and uploading files but now no submission on submit. Please help.

```js
 if ($(this).valid()){

            var submitContact = $('#submit_form'),
            message = $('#msg');

            submitContact.on('click', function(){
        
            var formData = new FormData($('#solid-form')[0]); 
              
            var $this = $(this);
            var recaptchaResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
             if(recaptchaResponse.length!=0){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'job.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache:false,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    data: formData,
                    success: function(data) {

                    if(data.info !== 'error'){
                    $this.parents('form').fadeOut("slow");
                           // $this.parents('form').find('input[type=text],textarea,select').filter(':visible').val('');
                            message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('success').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow');
                        } else {
                            message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('error').html(data.msg).fadeIn('slow');
                        }
                      }
                    });
                 }else{
                   message.hide().removeClass('success').removeClass('error').addClass('error').html("Please validate reCaptcha.").fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
                 }
                });
          }
          
           event.preventDefault();

        });
        });
```

```js
<?php 

 /* ==========================  Define variables ========================== */

 #Your e-mail address
 define("__TO__", "asjadrex@gmail.com");
 

 #Message subject
 define("__SUBJECT__", "Website Visitor Message");

 #Success message
 define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Thanks for your interest in Sapphire! <br> We will review your information and get back to you.");

 #Error message 
 define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Error, your message hasn't been sent");

 #Messege when one or more fields are empty
 define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__', "Please fill out  all fields");

 /* ========================  End Define variables ======================== */

 //Send mail function
 function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
  if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
   echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
  } else {
   echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
  }
 }

 //Check e-mail validation
 function check_email($email){
  if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$", $email)){
   return false;
  } else {
   return true;
  }
 }
 function check_phone($phone){
  if(strlen($phone)==10){
   return true;
  } else {
   return false;
  }
 }

 //Get post data
 if(isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['phone'])){
  $fname   = $_POST['firstname'];
  $lname   = $_POST['lastname'];
  $email   = $_POST['email'];
  $phone   = $_POST['phone'];
  $address   = $_POST['address'];
  $city   = $_POST['city'];
  $state   = $_POST['state'];
  $zip   = $_POST['zip'];

  $uscitizen   = $_POST['uscitizen'];
  $work_loc  = $_POST['work_loc'];
  $positions   = $_POST['positions'];
  

  if(isset($_FILES['headshot'])){
       $errors= array();
       $file_name = $_FILES['headshot']['name'];
       $file_size =$_FILES['headshot']['size'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['headshot']['tmp_name'];
       $file_type=$_FILES['headshot']['type'];
       $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['headshot']['name'])));
      
       move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
       /*$headshot_link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/DemoSite/uploads/".$file_name;*/
    }


     if(isset($_FILES['resume'])){
       $errors= array();
       $file_name = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
       $file_size =$_FILES['resume']['size'];
       $file_tmp =$_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
       $file_type=$_FILES['resume']['type'];
       $file_ext=strtolower(end(explode('.',$_FILES['resume']['name'])));
      
          move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
         /* $resume_link = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . "/DemoSite/uploads/".$file_name;*/
    }

   

  /*if($name == '') {
   echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your name."));
   exit();
  } else if($mail == '' or check_email($mail) == false){
   echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter valid e-mail."));
   exit();
  } else if($phone == '' or check_phone($phone) == false){
   echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Enter valid Phone Number (10 digit Max)"));
   exit();
  } else if($comment == ''){
   echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your message."));
   exit();
  } else {*/
   //Send Mail
   $to = __TO__;
   $subject = __SUBJECT__;
   $message = '
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>Mail from '. $fname .' '. $lname .'</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th align="right">First Name:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $fname .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Last Name:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $lname .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">E-mail:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $email .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Type Event:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $phone .'</td>
    </tr>
    ';
    
    $message .='<tr>
      <th align="right">Street Address:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $address .'</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <th align="right">City:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $city .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right"> State:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $state .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right"> Zip Code:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $zip .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right"> U.S. Citizen:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $uscitizen .'</td>
    </tr>
    ';


    $message .='<tr>
      <th align="right">Work Location:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $work_loc .'</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Position:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $positions .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Link to Headshot:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $headshot_link .'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="right">Link to Resume:</th>
      <td align="left">'. $resume_link .'</td>
    </tr>
     </table>
   </body>
   </html>
   ';

   $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
   /*$headers .= 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";*/
   $headers .= 'From: onlinebooking@nysapphire.com'."\r\n";

   send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
   
  }
 else {
  echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __MESSAGE_EMPTY_FILDS__));
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Please check on that link using firebug! It actually does not give any error just highlights jquery.min.js